# Blocking Retry in spring kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring-kafka-3.0.6.

I want to implement blocking retry in spring kafka, so I have written this below code. Please let me know is there anything that I have missed.

**Scenario:** while processing the records if I got an exception of `RetryableException` then I want to retry for 2 times and if retry exhausted then I want to send to custom dead letter queue with fixed partition.

```
@KafkaListener(
            autoStartup = "false",
            containerFactory = "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            id = "demoConsumer",
            groupId = "demoConsumerGroup",
            topics = "demoTopicName"
    )
    public void consumeMessage(
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) String partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) String timestamp,
            ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord,
            Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

        try {
            log.info("log something");
            // process message
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex instanceof RetryableException) {
                throw ex;
            }
            log.error("log something");
        }

    }
```

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfig {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;


    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setStopImmediate(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(defaultErrorHandler());

        return factory;
    }

    public CommonErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler() {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer(),
                new FixedBackOff(0L, 2L));
    }

    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer() {
        final BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition>
                CUSTOMIZE_DESTINATION_RESOLVER = (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition("topicName" + ".DLT", 0);

        return new
                DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate, CUSTOMIZE_DESTINATION_RESOLVER);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question exactly? If you want to ignore all other exceptions, you should acknowledge.

Comment: The question is that the above code written is correct for blocking retry ? Retry for 2 times and if retry is exhausted then send the message in custom Dead letter queue. The catch block I will correct as I need to acknowledge. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yes it is correct, but why ask? Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. @GaryRussell . Actually when I was running initially I saw it was trying for 5 times and message was not getting into DLQ. Later, I realised I forgot to mention serialization property for producing to DLQ, After correcting it, now It is working fine.